# case when filter is empty - select all

Tags: sql-server

I need to add a state filter to the procedure. When filter is not empty like 'AL', 'AK' etc all works fine, but if filter is empty I should return all rows.

```
where ... and state = case when @stateFilter != '' then @stateFilter else ??? end
```

Comment: The problem was resolved. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @Cid Thank you for advice. Done it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may rephrase your logic as follows:

```
WHERE
    ... AND
    (state = @stateFilter OR @stateFilter = '');
```

The last condition would return true if the `state` equals the variable passed in, *or* the variable passed in happens to be empty string.

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix might be something like this:

and state LIKE case when @stateFilter != '' then @stateFilter else '%' end